# In chrome dev tools, how to disable `disable cache` default setting?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Whenever I open the console this button is always checked. Each time I need to uncheck the box. I want the box to be disabled on default.

Comment: This solution works for me
[Chrome devtools network tab "disable cache" checkbox always remains checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76801176/chrome-cannot-disable-disable-cache)

Answer (score 1):

If the Disable Cache checkbox automatically checked after each refresh, it may be due to the "Devtools - Sources - Overrides - Enable Local Overrides" feature being enabled.

[see feature path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5ivn.png)

So just uncheck "Enable Local Overrides".

Answer (score 0):

1. Open dev tools by cmd + option + J
2. Click on the 3 dots at the top right
3. Click on settings

[image]

4. Scroll down in preferences
5. Find networks
6. Uncheck disable cache box

[image]