# Chrome cannot disable "disable cache"

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Whenever I disable (toggle off/turn off/uncheck) the "disable cache" checkbox on the Chrome devtools network tab, once closing the devtools window, reopen a window on a tab, it instantly and automatically does re-check the "disable cache" checkbox. Is this a bug? I don't remember if I have done some kind of permanent "disable cache" in the past, but the behavior is apparently weird. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can't disable cache due to performance problem. It is same problem on other browser such as FireFox, Chromium, Brave, Opera.

Comment: No, it's not about "disabling cache"... it's about "disabling Disable Cache"...

Comment: I've started seeing the same behaviour with the 115 update. Highly annoying.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was disabling local overrides on the "Sources" tab
[uncheck Enable Local Overrides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFt6g.png)